# MySQL client suddenly connects with external IP

Tags: mysql, linux

After a while (weeks) not working with MySQL 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log, now when I try to connect I get:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'DD.D.DDD.DDD' (using password: YES)
```

(D are the digits of my external IP)

I have no problem if I use

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

Why is it now using my external IP? I have no changes under /etc/mysql

Comment: Check what location is set for root (where from on the Users & Privileges Management tab). The location may have been set for a specific IP address & if you have a dynamic address & that changed you will no longer have access.

Comment: Why would a change in MySQL cause this? It's not connecting itself is it. You (or your package manager) changed something in routing, causing localhost traffic to be routed externally. A quick glance at the output of `route` should clarify this. The question is highly offtopic on SO though.

Comment: See privileges in `mysql.user`. Is it possible to have new IP assigned by your ISP?

Answer (score 1):

left in a vacuum it guess since you did not specify `-h host` in first attempt. It marches down mysql.user and finds the first match for the wildcard. And your entered password did not match it.

running a `select * from mysql.user` might shed some light on it. You might find entries such as:

```
Host            User
172.31.2.202    root
localhost       root
%               root
127.0.0.1       root
```

**Edit:**

Sometimes you need to do a:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'www.xxx.yyy.zzz' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Followed by the necessary grants for that user. Above where I say root, it is just an example. I would not do root !

Also, do not put a space after -u, so it is not -u root, it is **-uroot**

Comment: With
 select DISTINCT(Host) from mysql.user;
I only get :127.0.0.1 and localhost